# Improve the quality of an image when I put it into a pdf using reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to put an JPG image into a PDF using reportlab like follow, in python language.

`p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
   p.drawImage(filename_jpg_image,x,y)`

The problem here is that the image displayed in the pdf does not have the same quality as the original one. I want to know if there are a way to specify the quality in this context, or improve it anyway. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most tools that put JPEGs into PDFs will uncompress and then (badly) recompress the JPEG.

[img2pdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/img2pdf/0.1.5) can wrap many (most?) JPEG images into PDFs without changing the compression (without decompressing at all, in fact).

Then you can use [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) to pull that PDF onto the reportlab canvas as a form xObject (similar to an image).  There are a few examples in the pdfrw/examples/rl1 directory that show how to do this.

Disclaimer: I am the pdfrw author.